# Negative covariance in SEM

Tags: covariance, structural-equation-modeling

How to interpret covariance, negative and non-significant in the testing data set, when the same covariance in the training set appears to be small, but significant and of positive sign? Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged this with sem - but training and testing sets are not common in sem (as defined in the tag). Was that correct?

Comment: If you are getting a negative covariance (and it is indeed SEM - structural equation modeling as referenced by the tag), then it is usually an issue of model misspecification.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you have divided a dataset into a training and a test set. SEM is not a preferred predictive tool as compared to other network methods. Nonetheless, it is interesting to consider dividing (into adequately powered subsets) a training and test set to qualitatively compare the inference drawn from performing the same model in both sets.

Assuming you've met those conditions, what you see may merely be a fluke of the dataset selection procedure.

A somewhat more grave possibility is that of overfitting. If the training dataset was used to select a final model from among a sequence of models based upon some "choice" criteria (such as statistical significance), it's possible you are catching a spurious finding.

The covariance summarizes a bidirectional edge between two nodes in a network, conditional upon all their latent and measured "ancestors" if the network structure follows a DAG. A negative covariance indicates a negative relationship, as with a linear regression model, where a higher value of one node is associated with a lower value in the other. Statistical significance of these terms is based on a test of variance components in a multivariate normal model.

It can be difficult to ascertain power of the tests of covariance in SEM. They depend on the more sophisticated structure of the network, specifically that of the ancestor node(s) where present. For that reason, a simple "n" may not be enough to determine if an analysis is adequately powered.